# How can I get an article from wiki with a specific language using python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mediawiki

I want to get an article in wiki for a specific language.

I tried the following code :

```
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
PARAMS = {
        "action": "query",
        "titles": "Python",
        "prop": "langlinks",
        "lllang": "de",
        "format": "json"
        }
results = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

But I didn't get the whole article all I git is this

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"46332325":{"pageid":46332325,"ns":0,"title":"Python","langlinks":[{"lang":"de","*":"Python"}]}}}}
```

Can you help to understand what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL to `de.wikipedia.org` to get German version.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"  # <-- note the de.
PARAMS = {
        "action": "parse",
        "page": "Python (Programmiersprache)",
        "prop": "text",
        "section": 0,
        "format": "json"
        }

results = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(results['parse']['text']['*'], 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="mw-parser-output">
 <table cellspacing="5" class="float-right infobox toccolours toptextcells" style="font-size:90%; margin-top:0; width:21em;">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th class="hintergrundfarbe6" colspan="2" style="font-size:larger;">
     Python
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>

... and so on.
```

---

To get only wiki template/tags, you can do:

```
URL = "https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
PARAMS = {
        "action": "query",
        "titles": "Python (Programmiersprache)",
        "prop": "revisions",
        "rvprop": "content",
        "rvsection": 0,
        "format": "json"
        }

results = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS).json()
print(results)
```

Comment: But the problem is that I want to have a function that for a specific title and specific language it gives you the article in this language. That's why I need the URL to be general.

Comment: Why not just edit the API URL based on your function - that is still "general"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wikipedia page title in one language, and you want to know the title in another language, you can use the "langlinks" propertly, like so:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=Python+(programming+language)&lllang=de

Note the "lllang" set to "de"

This gives you:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "23862": {
                "pageid": 23862,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Python (programming language)",
                "langlinks": [
                    {
                        "lang": "de",
                        "*": "Python (Programmiersprache)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See here for more information:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Langlinks